# Modal form in ASP.NET using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I'm relatively new to ASP.NET development, have so far managed to keep things simple but I now have a little more complex of a requirement and so far not getting much joy.

Essentially I'd like to have a modal form pop up when a button is clicked to add a new user, so I've found [this on the jQuery site](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) which I think is the sort of thing I'm looking for but I'm really struggling to figure out what the appropriate way is to add this to an ASP.NET project / page.

Any advice would be highly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to include a reference to `jQuery` and `jQuery UI`.

You then need to make a container for your dialog, such as:

```
 <div id="dialog">
    <p>
       Your content here
    </p>
 </div>
```

You then need to create the dialog, i.e. when the `DOM` loads:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, height: 200, width: 200 });
  });
```

Then to open your dialog with a button, you can add a simple `HTML` button and attach that via jQuery.

```
<input type="button" ID="btnDialog" value="Click here to open the dialog" />
```

Then to attach to `jQuery`:

```
$("#btnDialog").click(function() {
   $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

**JS Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/VtZYD/

Ensure `jQuery` is loaded as well as `jQuery UI`

This should be placed in your `<head>` section:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src=http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

You can also include the `CSS` files using a `link` tag:

```
 <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this @darren-davies, sorry for being thick but where would you place the Javascript?  In the Head content section of the aspx page I'm working on I added your code inside a <script> tag and I get "Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined" when it hits the first line. Thanks!

Comment: @ebooyens - you need to include the jQuery reference in the <head> section yes. I'll update my answer to include the CDN version of `jQuery`.  Remember you need `jQuery UI` for the Dialog.  And we were all new once so not to worry :)

Comment: @DarrenDavies - +1 one of the best answers I've seen posted on SO. Wish everyone was so elaborate in their examples and explainations (including me!)

Comment: Nice comprehensive answer @DarrenDavies, you even threw in a jsfiddle :)

Comment: I think your answer is all good but I'm afraid I can't get it to work in my ASP.NET project.  There must be other things in the project causing problems - I now don't get any errors but nothing happens when I click the button.  If I set autoOpen to true it shows up but looks quite strange, no borders for example, and the close link appears and does hide it when clicked.  So I'll play around, don't expect you to try and sort this under this question. Thanks again!

Comment: @ebooyens - Just ensure that all the jQuery libraries are loaded correctly in the project.  The code works in the fiddle I provided that's because jQuery is loaded, I assume the libraries have not been loaded correctly.  If you still encounter a problems you can always ask another question and hopefully I can help further.  Good luck.

Comment: After some help from @Remy it now works, he suggested this which has done it, thanks!
`jQuery(function($) {
        $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, height: 200, width: 200 });
        $("#dialog").parent().appendTo("form:first");

        $("#btnNewCandidate").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
    });`