# How to validate a field is not empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view as abcd.cshtml with below code

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {                
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.createtime)

            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.general)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.general)
            </div>
            <a class="anchor" id="keywords"></a>
            <h3>Keywords</h3>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.keywords)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.keywords)
            </div>
            <a class="anchor" id="relatedcq"></a>
            <h3>Related CQ</h3>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.relatedcq)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.relatedcq)
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </p>

        }

    </div>
```

The controller is simple abcd.cs, I just put this into a DB

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult Create(staging staging)
        {
            staging.modifiedby = User.Identity.Name;
            staging.lastmodified = DateTime.Now;
            staging.createtime = DateTime.Now;
            try
            {
                db.stagings.Add(staging);
                db.SaveChanges();                
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                ViewData["error"] = "An error has occured: " + e.Message;
                return View(staging);
            }
                        return RedirectToAction("Details/" + staging.id);
        }
```

What I want is to make sure that Keywords is filled. If Keywords is filled I need to have a pop up window saying "Please fill the Keywords".
I tried doing that using MessageBox.Show() but then for that I had to add System.Windows.Forms and that had some conflicts with System.Web.Mvc;

Comment: you'll probably just need some custom javascript that is executed before the postback to the controller.

Comment: or you can use client-side validation and make `keywords` a required field.  That'd be the way of 'letting the framework handle it for you'

Comment: what does your model look like?

Comment: `MessageBox.Show()` would execute on server side not on browser. you need to write a custom validation rule and apply it to keywords model. On validation failed you can take custom action e.g. showing a Modal popup using JQuery.

Comment: [MVC - Adding Validation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation)

Comment: @user3917144 you can achieve it by creating a custom validation attribute. see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using htmlhelper ValidationMessageFor would'nt you rather display a Validation Summary to the user the shows him/her all the fields that you require filled in?

e.g.
If you have a model and you have multiple fields that need to be filed in, which can be validated by decorating those fields/properties with the `[Required]` attribute, or any other that you see fit e.g. `[StringLength]` etc.

If you do that you can provide a validation summary, using the model binder to not post youre data if it doesnt meet the set validation.
[image]
Validation summary example:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please provide the details above and then click submit.")
```

That above will display all the validation errors of all fields marked with the following e.g. `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.relatedcq)`

Image of how the output, if there are validation errors, will be displayed.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: adding [Required] was the first thing I tried based on some suggestions I got from some forums but then it always threw me error while the db.SaveChanges() was called.

And where exactly should I add the ValidationSummary in the code? In the cshtml file itself or in the controller?

Comment: If it crashes at db.savechanges then have you checked the exception thrown? Have you checked the value by breakpointing in the section. If you have validation set and the form doesnt meet those requirenents of the validation it wont post. Add the required field and put the  validation summary right after the submit button to detail all the errors. Also you may want to add some meaningful comment as to why its failing validation.

Comment: Ok I think I got this done partially by referring to http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation

now by adding ModelState.Valid it gives me doesn't allow me to submit and it prints the error message beside the keywords box.

Now will it possible to help me out on how I make the relevant box "RED" and the * field as displayed in your example?

Comment: Thats done through CSS. Add this css to youre css file and reference that css file in your view. I've added comments. Maybe click accept answer?

/*styles for html validation helpers*/
.field-validation-error {
    color: #ff0000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

/*the textbox input with red border*/
input.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #ac2828;
}

/*the textarea input with red border*/
intput[type=text], textarea.input-validation-error{
    border: 1px solid #ac2828;
}

.validation-summary-errors{
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to create a custom validation attribute on server side. So for e.g. Let's name it as MustBeFilled. Your new attribute would look like:

```
public class MustBeFilledAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable // IClientValidatable for client side Validation
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(null));
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var modelClientValidationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ValidationType = "mustbefilled",
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage //Added
        };

        modelClientValidationRule.ValidationParameters.Add("param", metadata.DisplayName); //Added
        return new List<ModelClientValidationRule> { modelClientValidationRule };
    }
}
```

Now you would need a client side script as well to take action if the rule fails. As in your case you want to show a popup. Add below to your site script and make sure it renders after the `Jquery-validation-*` scripts are rendered.

```
(function ($) {
    $.validator.addMethod('mustbefilled', function (value, element, params) {

        if ($(element).val() != '')
            return true;

        alert('Fill it first.');
        // Here you need to Invoke the modal popup.

        return false;
    }, '');

    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('mustbefilled', ['param'], function (options) {
        options.rules["mustbefilled"] = '#' + options.params.requiredif;
        options.messages['mustbefilled'] = options.message;
    });

})(jQuery);
```

To apply this custom validation, first add the attribute on your Model property.

```
[MustBeFilled]
public string Keywords { get; set; }
```

Then add the custom javascript to bundle.config, only if you have kept the code in separate file named `mustbefilled.js`. Here I intentionally added the javascript file with validation plugin so you don't get exception if it rendered before the validation plugin.

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                  "~/Scripts/mustbefilled.js"));
```

That's it you're all set.

Now all you have to do is create a model pop and call it in the `mustbefilled.js` where I placed the comment to invoke it. See this [sample here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18587747/881798) which would help you create a bound modal popup to your keywords property.

Comment: Why not just use the built in `[Required]` attribute?

Comment: Hmm may be!! If its allowed to customize client side scripting for required attrib. Yeah it shoud do the trick lemme try.

Comment: I knw abt required attrib bt the ques is what made me excited is to do something more than jst displaying a message. Thats why i was intersting in finding a silly bt intersting ans to this question. U knw no ques is stupid.